# How to list all open source components used in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, open-source

I need to create a list of all Open Source Components being used in my Rails application.

Is there a quick way to do this or I have to go through whole application and create the list?

Comment: Rails and all components used in standard rails distribution are open source. If you want to see the list of all components used, checkout Gemfile.lock.

Comment: `rails` with all the sub-components (activerecord, etc) used by rails is opensource .. unless you are using some heavily modified fork of rails sourced other than the one  from https://rubygems.org